# Creating an IIS site through setup

Tags: iis, setup-deployment

I want to create an IIS site with setup and deployment. How can I create an installer that creates an IIS site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately even in Visual Studio 2010 there still isn't a way to do this without resorting to custom install actions.